# Search the web using Google search engine and Java

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection, google-search

I'm trying to make a request on Google using Java and HttpURLConnection.
Below there is my code where im trying to make a request giving a domain.

```
public static void googleSearch(String domain) throws Exception {
        String response = null;
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-EN; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        map.put("User-Agent", userAgent);
        map.put("Host", "www.google.com");
        map.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/search?num=100&start=0&hl=en&meta=&q=%40%22"+domain+"%22");
        response = response + Utility.GETRequest(url, map);}
```

The GETRequest code is:

```
public static String GETRequest(URL url, Map<String, String> map){
    String readLine = null;
    String responseGET = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        if(map != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
                con.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((readLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(readLine);
                response.append('\r');
            } 
            in.close();
            responseGET = response.toString();
        } else {
            System.out.println("responseCode = "+responseCode);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }finally {
        if (con != null) {
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return responseGET;
}
```

The problem is that i receive everytime StatusCode = 429, Trying with the "https://www.google.com/se....." it's the same.
How can i fix it ? or, Should i use the Google client API?
I will be glad if some one can solve it.

Comment: do you know what [HTTP `429`](https://http.cat/429) is?

Comment: Yes, ofc, but im doing just a request...

Comment: ...too many of them, in fact

Comment: Maybe you should try to use a proxy, or an IP Reset. Don't know how many debug attempts you had, but maybe google is just blocking your requests with a 429.